# Plotly in Dash Python is not getting updated

Tags: python, plotly-dash

When I run the code i get the graph but the graph is not getting updated i am calling the data from my sql laptop sql management studio.

Kindly let me know what needs to be done the X axis contains date and time and Y axis contains data in numeric form which is getting updated automatically

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import numpy as np

server ='LAPTOP-OO3V36UA\SQLEXPRESS'
db='addy'

conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=' +server + ';DATABASE=' + db + 
';Trusted_connection=yes')

 sql="""

 SELECT * FROM Summry
```

"""

```
 df=pd.read_sql(sql ,conn)

import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
 from random import random
import plotly

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph-scatter', animate=True),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-component',
        interval=1*1000
    )
])

@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph-scatter', 'figure'),
          [Input('interval-component', 'interval')])

def update_graph_scatter():

df=pd.read_sql(sql ,conn)
trace1=go.Scatter(
y=df['ACL'],
x = df['DateandnTime'],
mode='lines',
name='ACL'

)
layout = go.Layout(
title='Daily Monitoring'
)
return {'data': trace1, 'layout': layout}
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server()
```

Comment: Did you run the function to constantly update?

Comment: Yes i want to basically take data from sql server it is contently coming and i want to make a live graph

Answer (score 1):

You've set your callback's input to

```
Input('interval-component', 'interval')
```

But you want

```
Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')
```

The `interval` property sets how frequently `n_intervals` gets updated. The change in `n_intervals` is what can be used to trigger the callback.

Here's the documentation: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval